# ZOD validation based on another field

Tags: typescript, zod

Imagine I have an object like

```js
{
  field1: 'test',
  field2: 'test1'
}
```

How I can create the following validation:

If `field1` and `field2` both are empty - it is not valid

If `field1` and `field2` both are not empty - it is not valid

Other cases are valid.

Comment: `type T = {field1: string, field2?: never} | {field1?: never, field2: string};` XORs two types together, I havent used ZOD though so I dont know if thats what you need.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`.refine()`](https://zod.dev/?id=refine):

```
const res = z.object({
    field1: z.string().optional(),
    field2: z.string().optional(),
}) 
    .refine(schema => {
        return !(
            schema.field1 === undefined && 
            schema.field2 === undefined ||
            schema.field2 !== undefined && 
            schema.field1 !== undefined
        ); 
    }, "Your message");
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use a ternary, just use your expression and it will result in true or false. eg: `refine(schema => schema.field1 === undefined)`